# Wicket nestedTree hangs internet explorer 10 after expand node

Tags: java, ajax, internet-explorer, tree, wicket

I have a problem with Wicket NestedTree in InternetExplorer 10/11.
When i have node, who has a hudge number children - near 5000, then after trying expand node ie hangs until i stop javascript executing. 
On firefox, opera, older version of ie (7 - 8) everything is ok, loading lasts only a few seconds.

NestedTree implementation is based on ajax requests and i wonder if newer versions of ie has a problem with hudge ajax requests. 
Problem is not on server side, because request executes fast.
When i tried profile IE in built-in profiler, i noticed fast memory usage growth after expand. Usage increased to 800 mb and then suspend. 
Did someone have a similar problem ?
Did someone have some ideas what can cause a problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem (IIRC) with huge ajax-i-fied components in Wicket is that each Ajax link / behaviour get one line of javascript that initializes it. For small numbers this is fine, but if you have a page that consists of 1000s of AjaxLinks, this gets slow.

There is a workaround that I use succesfully, and that is to replace all the AjaxLinks with Labels with `setOutputMarkupId(true)` and add a `OnChildEventBehaviour` (see [my github code](https://github.com/RobAu/wicket-jq-autocomplete/tree/master/jq-autocomplete/src/main/java/org/audenaerde/onchildeventbehavior)) to some parent element. Then, in this parent element, use the `event`'s component id to find the ID in the component tree.

Comment: Unfortunately, when i changed Ajax link component to plain Label, expanding node lasts still too long. Hovewer, browser doesn,t suspend totally, i don`t have to stop java script executing, but problem is that is too long. Have someone some another idea ?

It is strange that problem performs only on IE. What can cause it ?

Comment: The other reason it takes long is probably that you also have a lot of HTML which needs to be parsed... My experience though that the javascript should have done the trick. Can you inspect the DOM tree / source to see if the number of javascript lines is indeed decreases significantly? `Wicket.Ajax.ajax({"u":"....`? Maybe you still have some other javascript that takes long.

Comment: Indeed, i noticed, that in response html (request after expand node) i have a lot of lines with `Wicket.Ajax.ajax({"u":"....`

Comment: Then there are either more AjaxLinks, or AjaxBehaviors attached to the nodes. You can dig in to the source code of the Tree and try to find them and replace them with. It will be a nasty bit of work.

Comment: I tried also profile in IE profiler. According profiler the longest duration is durning function jquery - callback execution. For request that expand node with 190 children, in response i have script consist of 41078 signs

Comment: Yes, what you see is Wicket Ajax parsing and evaluating all the JavaScript callbacks. Wicket uses jQuery to perform all the ajax stuff.